# CSS, image with height:auto, covers div beneath it upon screen resize (phone held horizontally)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, position

I'm designing the mobile phone portion of my website. I have a, top:0%, position:fixed, banner image with, width:100%, and height:auto. As the phone is turned horizontally the banner image scales nicely covering the screen width.

However my issue is in positioning content below this image. For example a div with position:absolute, and top:20%, displays a div below the banner for a vertical screen. Unfortunately when turning the screen horizontally, the image enlarges, and covers the div. Is there a CSS solution that can grab the height of the image at any point and adjust its top percentage accordingly?

Edit: I'm also open to a javascript solution :) Thanks.

Comment: Short answer is: No.  You need a JavaScript aided solution.  If that is acceptable, please rephrase your question.

Comment: Damn. I was hoping for a CSS solve...What's the easiest way this can be handled with javascript? Cheers.

Comment: Yes I've implemented Jquery and plugins into this site too.

Comment: Could you not use `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) { }` to target landscape orientation on mobile devices? (You could have separate fluid `div` containers for the image and the content when in landscape mode that are set to `display:none;` on the desktop or portrait versions of the site)

Comment: @adaam The problem is the fixed header, which is out of flow, so the following block element needs to know the height of the fixed header element in order to have the right top offset (or margin or padding).  Media queries by themselves won't do it but may offer other advantages depending on the overall design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

For example, if this is the HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/400/100">
</div>
<div class="main">Some content...</div>
```

You can use the following CSS to fix-position your header and absolute-position your main block:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.header img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.main {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 147px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

To automatically reposition your `.main` block when the window re-sizes, you can use
the following jQuery:

```
function fixMainTop() {
    $(".main").css({
        "top": $(".header").outerHeight()
    });
}

fixMainTop();

$(window).resize(function () {fixMainTop();});
```

You call the `fixMainTop()` when the page load, and then whenever the window size changes.

However, the `$resize` function can lead to slightly jumpy looking screen, but I think that you can accept that since many websites using jQuery exhibit the same behavior.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/spxCj/

**PS**

You may not need the `.resize` action if the website has a fixed width... but it is good to see how it can be done.

Comment: Brilliant Marc. This works wonderfully. You saved me a few hours of trying to figure it out myself. I'd buy you a beer if you were in Melbourne :)

Comment: You are very welcome! I don't get to Melbourne too often, but the thought is most welcome!  In lieu of a pint, an up vote would be grand. All the best!