# how to prevent the header height from covering container beneath it and in the same time make it auto

Tags: html, css

I have a web page layout. consists of three parts. the layout is pretty simple and works fine. The problem for small screen the header expands and covers the container beneath it. My question is, how to make the header container expands and in the same time do not cover the container beneath it? Please exclude the fixed height. for example (Height: 150px;). the height must be set to auto or any mode that makes it responsive.

here is the HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="repeat.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="header-container">
    <div> 
        <ul class="left">
            <li>home</li>
            <li>menu</li>
            <li>links</li>
            <li>contacts</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li>home</li>
            <li>menu</li>
            <li>links</li>
            <li>contacts</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="main-container">

    <div class="left-column">
        <div class="wrap">

        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="main-column">
        <div>
            <p> this part should not be covered when the header 
            container change its height </p>
            <p> this part should not be covered when the header 
            container change its height </p>
            <p> this part should not be covered when the header 
            container change its height </p>
            <p> this part should not be covered when the header 
            container change its height </p>
            <p> this part should not be covered when the header 
            container change its height </p>
            <p> this part should not be covered when the header 
            container change its height </p>

        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The css code :

```
       * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.header-container{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 10;
}
.left{
    padding-left: 50px;
    float:left;
}
.right{
    padding-left: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.main-container{

    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 80px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: pink;
    z-index:1;
}
.left-column{
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #4db6ac;
}
.main-column{
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #00e5ff;
}

@media screen and (max-width:720px){
    .header-container{
        height: auto;
    }
    .left-column{
        display:none;
    }
    .main-column{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't give the container a height or give it a `min-height`, and as the child expands so will the parent, if it's a block level Element.

Comment: Or use `max-height` and `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: I do not want to hide any content in the header container and the other container . I want all contents to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution using the jQuery. The solution is posted by Marc Audet. You can find the solution following this link:
[CSS, image with height:auto, covers div beneath it upon screen resize (phone held horizontally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132850/css-image-with-heightauto-covers-div-beneath-it-upon-screen-resize-phone-hel?rq=1)

Please if any one has another solution using only css will be highly appreciated.